# Customize KDE tiling grid

Tags: kde, window-manager

In KDE, when the user is moving a window around with the mouse and she touches a border of the screen, a shadow appears showing the position the window will occupy if the user drops it there.

When the mouse is against the top border, the whole screen is offered, if it's against left or right borders near the middle, half of the screen is offered.  It it's against those borders but near the top or the bottom, a quarter of the screen is offered.

What I want is a way to configure that feature so the left side offers 4/5 of the screen and the right side offers 1/5 only.

On Windows XP I used to do it with GridMove: 
http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html

This particular utility allows the user to define drop zones that are linked to (usually similar) target areas where the window would appear positioned.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. If you don't hear anything here, you can try http://forum.kde.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I finally did is to create three shell scripts:

```
$ cat ~/bin/win1
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,fullscreen
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,1350,800
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert

$ cat ~/bin/win2
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,fullscreen
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,1355,0,315,800
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert

$ cat ~/bin/win3
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,fullscreen
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,300,1400,615,300
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

The first one puts current window in a big area at the left of my main screen (desktop monitor I have above the laptop display).  Let's call it "area 1".

The second one puts current window in a thin area at the right of that same screen.  This would be "area 2".

The combination of area 1 and area 2 covers the whole main monitor.

The third screen maximizes the current window at the notebook display below.

Obviously I defined the sizes using the numbers on the scripts because that's the grid I wanted.  You can define your own grid, see `man wmctrl` to find out how.

Next, I added those scripts to the KDE start menu.  You can open the KDE Menu Editor by right clicking on Application Launcher, then Edit Applications.
Last, I configured a different shortcut key for each one of them, right there in the KDE Menu Editor, under the "Advanced" tab.  I also unchecked "Enable launch feedback" under the "General" tab to get rid of the bouncing icon.

The shortcuts I used were Ctrl+Shift+1, Ctrl+Shift+2 and Ctrl+Shift+3.

I think that's pretty much it.